# Calculadora com inputs usando DOM

Tags: javascript

Se colocar número nos inputs e escolher a operação, deveria sair o resultado em um `alert`. Porém o alert não está funcionando.

```js
    let botao = document.getElementsByClassName('mybutton')
    botao.onclick = function(){
    let num1 =  Number(document.getElementById('num1').value)
    let num2 =  Number(document.getElementById('num2').value)
    let oper = document.getElementById('oper')
    let resultado = 0
    if(oper === '+'){
        resultado = num1 + num2
        alert(resultado)
    }else if(oper === '-'){
        resultado = num1 - num2
        alert(resultado)
    }else if( oper === '/'){
        resultado = num1 / num2
        alert(resultado)
    }else{
        resultado = num1*num2
        alert(resultado)
    }
}
```

```html
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8"> 
            <title> Calculadora em javascript</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Calculadora</h1>
            <form>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Digite o primeiro numero" id="num1">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Digite o segundo numero" id="num2">
                <input type="text" placeholder= "Digite a operação + - / * " id="oper">
                <button class="mybutton"> Calcular </button>
    
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: O seu código `script.js` está na pasta `js`? Como foi definido `<script src="js/script.js"></script>`.

Answer (score 4):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) retorna uma lista de elementos (note que o nome é `getElements`, no plural).

Então você deveria pegar somente o primeiro da lista para ter o botão (como só tem um, não tem problema fazer assim):

```js
// pega o primeiro elemento da lista retornada por getElementsByClassName
let botao = document.getElementsByClassName('mybutton')[0];
botao.onclick = function(e){
    let num1 =  Number(document.getElementById('num1').value);
    let num2 =  Number(document.getElementById('num2').value);
    let oper = document.getElementById('oper').value;
    if (oper === '+'){
        alert(num1 + num2);
    } else if(oper === '-'){
        alert(num1 - num2);
    } else if( oper === '/'){
        alert(num1 / num2);
    } else if (oper === '*') {
        alert(num1 * num2);
    } else {
        alert('operação inválida');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8"> 
            <title> Calculadora em javascript</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Calculadora</h1>
            <form>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Digite o primeiro numero" id="num1">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Digite o segundo numero" id="num2">
                <input type="text" placeholder= "Digite a operação + - / * " id="oper">
                <button class="mybutton"> Calcular </button>
    
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Repare também que para a operação você não estava pegando o `value`, então você estava comparando o `input` (e não o valor dele) com `+`, `-`, etc - e ele caía no último `else`, ou seja, sempre fazia a multiplicação. Usando o `value` e colocando um `if` a mais, fica melhor, pois agora ele valida todas as operações ou dá uma mensagem em caso de operação inválida.

E também usei `preventDefault` para evitar que o  `form` seja submetido e os dados da página "sumam" ao clicar no botão.

---

Claro que outra opção seria o botão ter um `id`:

```
<button id="mybutton"> Calcular </button>
```

Aí você poderia fazer:

```
document.getElementById('mybutton').onclick = function () {  etc...
```

Pois `id`'s devem ser únicos em uma página, e `getElementById` retorna um único elemento.

Comment: Obrigado pela excelente explicação amigo. Muita desatenção da minha parte. Ainda bem que temos na nossa comunidade, pessoas tão legais como você. Um abraço amigo

Comment: @ash Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema